# Axios (doesn't work) vs Postman (works) difference - Google OAuth2 call to refresh an access token

Tags: node.js, axios, postman, google-oauth

I'm using the Google OAuth2 flow, writing a function that takes a refresh_token I've saved to the database and makes the call to obtain a refreshed access_token. The problem is that when I make the call via Postman, it succeeds, but when I try to do it in the code via axios, it fails.

My Postman configuration for the call looks like this:
[image: Postman screenshot]

My code snippet looks like this:

```
export const getNewAccessToken = async (refreshToken: string): Promise<string> => {
    const url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';
    const data = {
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    };

    try {
        let res = await axios.post(url, data, {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
        }).then(response => {
            debugger;
        }).catch(e => {
            // It always enters the 'catch' here
            debugger;
        });
    } catch (e) {
        debugger;
    }
}
```

I've checked and the refresh_token I'm using to test this, client_id and client_secret are the same in both cases.

When I make this call, the error in the `catch` shows a 400 Bad Request, and the response.data is {error: 'unsupported_grant_type', error_description:'Invalid grant_type: '}

Am I missing something obvious? What can I try to do to debug?

One thing I've tried is to look at the error `e` to see what request is being made, but I can't seem to find where the original request is in that ClientRequest object.

**Edit 1:**

Here's the curl command from Postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=[confirmed same refresh_token as the code]' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=[ditto]' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=[ditto]' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token'
```

Comment: Get the curl command from Postman and share it here. By the way, are those process.env values defined? What about debugger them? And last thing, why are you mixing async/await and .then ? Just resolve with await, then .json() the result

Comment: You aren't URL encoding the body, see here https://axios-http.com/docs/urlencoded

Comment: Ah - @Aurast, you're right! Do you want to post as an answer? I was able to achieve this with node's querystring: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

Comment: Good to hear, yes I will write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give Axios a JavaScript object to send as a request body, Axios will serialize it to JSON. But in this case, you are setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which signals intent to provide a URL-encoded body, not JSON. A URL-encoded body looks like this:

```
refresh_token=abc&grant_type=abc&client_id=abc&client_secret=abc
```

There are quite a few different ways to create such a string to send as the body, a number of which are detailed in the [Axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/urlencoded). I personally would do the following:

```js
const data = new URLSearchParams({
  refresh_token: refreshToken,
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
});
```

Alternatively, it *might* also work if you just set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` instead, but that depends on the API and whether it is able to accept JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
export const getNewAccessToken = async (refreshToken: string): Promise<string> => {
    const url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';
    const data = new URLSearchParams({
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    });

    try {
        let res = await axios.post(url, data, {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'
            },
        }).then(response => {
            debugger;
        }).catch(e => {
            // It always enters the 'catch' here
            debugger;
        });
    } catch (e) {
        debugger;
    }
}
```